# Difference between expression: while(str[i] != '\0') and while (str[i])

Tags: c++, c, while-loop, expression, equality

Is there any difference between those 2 expressions when it comes to checking whether or not we come to the end of the string?

```
while(str[i] != '\0')
```

And

```
while (str[i])
```

Where `str` has type `char*` and `i` is an integer.

Comment: The first is self-documenting code means "while the character is not null terminator" and the second can either mean that, or it can mean "This is some nonsense since I actually meant to take the address of the item and compare against null".

Answer (score 11):

In fact there is no difference. Any expression that evaluates to a non-zero value is considered as a logical true expression. And an expression that evaluates to zero is considered as a logical false expression.

From the C Standard (6.8.5 Iteration statements)

> 4 An iteration statement causes a statement called the loop body to be
> executed repeatedly until the controlling expression compares equal to
> 0. The repetition occurs regardless of whether the loop body is entered from the iteration statement or by a jump.1

Pay attention to that in C an expression with an equality operator has as value either 1 or 0.

So the expression `str[i] != '\0'`  yields 1 (non-zero value) if the relation is true or -0 otherwise.

In C++ the type of such an expression is `bool` and its value is either true or false.

From the C++ 14 Standard (4.12 Boolean conversions)

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer
> to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero
> value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted
> to false; any other value is converted to true. For
> direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be
> converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.